# Provide link/Redirect after a 'Like' or 'Share' on Facebook or a 'Share' on Twitter

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, twitter, share

basically what I want to do is forward people to a download link once they either 'like' my page on Facebook or post a link of the page to their profile (whatever is easier) and something similar for Twitter.

I have seen some bands do this when promoting a free download — to download the new song you must post this to your profile etc.

Anybody know how I could go about this? (This isn't a 'can you do it for me' question, I just need a point in the right direction regarding API's or any examples)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `edge.create` event in **Facebook** javascript SDK. This hits after you've liked something.
You can also create a Facebook app and check the likes of a Facebook user with their permission on the server side using FQL (`user_likes`).

You can create a **Twitter** app and read the last few tweets to check if there is a tweet containing your text/link/whatever programatically.

Notice that all of these can be deleted easily after you've redirected them. **You cannot avoid that.**

Answer (score 0):

[This Page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) has the like button attributes. Look under FAQ and you will see "How do I know when a user clicks a Like button?"